Mariadb crashed without a reason in ubuntu server 24.04
mysql is out. I don't know why.
I tryed to
apt install mysql-server --reinstall

it but it still doesn't work.
I obtain this error:

Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'

I made
dpkg -l | grep -e mysql-server -e mariadb-server    

and obtained
rc  mariadb-server                       1:10.11.8+maria~ubu2204                      amd64        MariaDB database server binaries                                                                                                                                     ii  mysql-server                         8.0.37-0ubuntu0.24.04.1                       all          MySQL database server (metapackage depending on the latest version)                                                                                                               
ii  mysql-server-8.0                     8.0.37-0ubuntu0.24.04.1                       amd64        MySQL database server binaries and system database setup                                                                                                                          
ii  mysql-server-core-8.0                8.0.37-0ubuntu0.24.04.1                       amd64        MySQL database server binaries 

may you help me please?
what can I do?
thank you very mutch

Which apt os? Are you installing MariaDB or mysql-sever? because there is conflicts between your title and the content. What was installed previously. What do you mean "frozen" - what have you observed that leads to this conclusion?

Thank you for your replay. I'm in a ubuntu server version 24.04. I installed mysql-server. Now I'm not able to use db because i I call mysqldump to make a dump of a database I obtain the error "Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock" and so for all other operations.

MariaDB cannot install on top of mysql-server (8.0+).
mysql-server cannot install on top of mariadb-server.
Your /var/lib/mysql probably contains something. If its data you wish to keep, export it with mariadb-dump/mysqldump, purge off /var/lib/mysql.
There are configuration differences between MySQL and MariaDB. Unless you have something known to work with both in /etc/mysql, its probably safer to just remove and add configuration items after installation.
Then proceed with installation.
